Laravel Google drive integration "masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext": "^2.3.0" package is not working for laravel 11
Laravel Google drive integration "masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext": "^2.3.0" package is not working for laravel 11
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Admin\AdminController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Masbug\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveAdapter;
use Masbug\Flysystem\GoogleDrive\GoogleDriveServiceProvider;

class GoogleDriveController extends AdminController
{
    protected $client;

    protected $folder_id;

    protected $service;

    protected $adapter;

    protected $serviceProvider;

    protected $ClientId = '###';

    protected $ClientSecret = '###';

    protected $refreshToken = '###';

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->client = new \Google_Client();
        $this->client->setClientId($this->ClientId);
        $this->client->setClientSecret($this->ClientSecret);
        $this->client->refreshToken($this->refreshToken);
        $this->service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
        $this->folder_id = '1zQA5vLXEOnDVQ9ePPKfyiXUPbPxfJhT_';

        $this->adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter([
            'clientId' => $this->client->setClientId($this->ClientId),
            'clientSecret' => $this->client->setClientSecret($this->ClientSecret),
            'refreshToken' => $this->client->refreshToken($this->refreshToken),
            $this->service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client),
        ]);

        $this->serviceProvider = new GoogleDriveServiceProvider($this->adapter);

        // Set the folder ID
        $this->folder_id = '1zQA5vLXEOnDVQ9ePPKfyiXUPbPxfJhT_';
    }

    public function create_folder_in_parent($folderName, $parentFolderID)
    {
        $fileMetadata = [
            'name' => $folderName,
            'parents' => [$parentFolderID],
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        ];

        $folder = $this->serviceProvider->createDirectory($folderName, $parentFolderID);

        return $folder['id'];
    }

    public function check_if_folder_exists($folderName, $folderID)
    {
        $folders = $this->serviceProvider->listContents('/', true);

        foreach ($folders as $folder) {
            if ($folder['type'] == 'dir' && $folder['basename'] == $folderName) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function upload_image($todayFolderID, $imageToBeUploaded, $imageName)
    {
        $result = $this->serviceProvider->write($todayFolderID.'/'.$imageName, $imageToBeUploaded);

        return $result;
    }

    public function getShareableLink($fileID)
    {
        $file = $this->serviceProvider->getMetadata($fileID);

        return $file['url'];
    }

    protected function remove_duplicated($fileName)
    {
        $files = $this->serviceProvider->listContents('/', true);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if ($file['type'] == 'file' && $file['basename'] == $fileName) {
                $this->serviceProvider->delete($file['path']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function upload_files()
    {
        $files = Storage::files();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $this->remove_duplicated($file);
            $read = Storage::get($file);
            $this->upload_image($this->folder_id, $read, basename($file));
            Storage::delete($file);
        }
    }

    public function files_count()
    {
        $files = $this->serviceProvider->listContents($this->folder_id, true);

        return count($files);
    }
}

I upgrade laravel 6 to laravel 10
in laravel 10 it is not working.
Please provide me better solution for it.

Try to install, works for me for Laravel 11

composer require masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext

